# Boot Option : ACPI=off

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, live-usb, acpi

acpi=off is the only way to USB Live Ubuntu/Lubuntu, which eventually shows up only 1 processor (for i7 6700HQ), no power option, no brightness control etc.  There are couple of people suffering from the same,

[Unable to run Ubuntu on a MSI laptop without disabling ACPI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/734872/unable-to-run-ubuntu-on-a-msi-laptop-without-disabling-acpi/772014#772014)

[Sony VAIO laptop SVF11N11CLB not start Ubuntu 16.04 without acpi = off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766167/sony-vaio-laptop-svf11n11clb-not-start-ubuntu-16-04-without-acpi-off/771994#771994)

[Booting Ubuntu with "acpi=off" grub parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1336451

How to resolve the issue? Such that processor, power options, brightness control and other ubuntu options are normalized. Such things need to be sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same processor. Have you tried `nomodeset`?

If you have an nvidia optimus machine like me probably nouveau is freezing the computer on boot.If that's the case you can try `nouveau.modeset=0`. In my case only this is needed.

Nvidia is hostile to free open source drivers and newer cards are very problematic with nouveau. After that you should be able to install the propietary drivers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried `nouveau.blacklist = 1` without any positive outcome. The only thing which worked was `acpi=off`. I have also tried Lubuntu/ Scientific Linux7.2/ Mint, only `acpi=off` works.

Comment: thnx, it worked. `nouveau.modeset=0` was the solution, not `nouveau.blackslist=1`.